# Total Probabilty theorem for demonstration the conditional probability expression

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Let $U_{1}, ...,U_{i}$ independent random variables $U[0,1]$. Define

$$ I_{1} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1\ & \quad \text{if  $U_{1}$ < $\frac{k}{n}$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwize}
  \end{array} \right.$$
and

$$ I_{i} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1\ & \quad \text{if   $U_{i+1}$ < $\frac{k-(I_{1}+...+I_{i})}{n-i}$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwize}
  \end{array} \right.$$

demonstrate with:
$$P[I_{1}=1] = \frac{k}{n}$$
and
$$P[I_{i+1}=1|I_{1},...,I_{i}]=\frac{k-\sum_{j=1}^{i}I_{j}}{n-i},1<i<n$$

I have shown the first part ($P[I_{1}=1]=\frac{k}{n}$), just could not take the step of induction to demonstrate the rest

Obs: The k be the size of the sample, $k< n$

Comment: Yes. Induction should work.   (NB: I suspect the second formula should be: $I_{i+1} = \ldots$, to avoid being self-referential.)

Comment: I have no ideia how to proceed. I tried baye's theorems, nothing.

Comment: $P[I_{i+1}=1|I_{1},...,I_{i}]$ just says: "the probability that the attempt $(i+1)$ results in $1$, when given results for the first $i$ attempts."

Comment: Actually, you don't need induction.  Just use the same reasoning as for the first step.  Since we have a uniform distribution, divide the domain of the event by the total domain.